# Limit of a stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $W_t$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and I would like to prove

$$\lim_{\beta\rightarrow+\infty}\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\left|e^{-\beta t} \int_0^te^{\beta s}\mathrm dW_s\right|=0$$

This is an exercise in Chapter 3 of *Karatzas&Shreve*, but I don't think this proposition is true since

$$\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\left|e^{-\beta t} \int_0^te^{\beta s}\mathrm dW_s\right|\geq \left|e^{-\beta T} \int_0^Te^{\beta s}\mathrm dW_s\right|:=|G|$$

where $G$ is a centered Gaussian random variable of variance $(1-e^{-2\beta T})/2\beta$, which implies the precedent proposition can not be true. Could someone tell me where I am wrong or this proposition is not true? Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you think that what you've stated implies the result does not hold? (The variance of your $G$ goes to zero as $\beta$ increases.)

Comment: This question has been answered on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120438/limit-of-a-wiener-integral

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered [on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120438/limit-of-a-wiener-integral). The key was an integration by parts argument.